# Triggered removeEventLister if addEventListener has been triggered once

Tags: javascript, boolean, addeventlistener, removeeventlistener

i want my event to be deleted if a file already been uploaded.
In other words, i want only one attachment to be added. But my 'active' variable is never equal to 'false'

````js
const form = document.querySelector("form"),
    fileInput = document.querySelector(".file-input"),
    progressArea = document.querySelector(".progress-area"),
    uploadedArea = document.querySelector(".uploaded-area"),
    clickedItem = document.querySelector(".clickkk");
let active = true;

if (active) {
    clickedItem.addEventListener("click", () => {
        fileInput.click();
    });
} else {
    clickedItem.removeEventListener("click", () => {
        fileInput.click();
    });
}

fileInput.onchange = ({ target }) => {
    let file = target.files[0];
    if (file) {
        let fileName = file.name;
        if (fileName.length >= 12) {
            let splitName = fileName.split('.');
            fileName = splitName[0].substring(0, 13) + "... ." + splitName[1];
        }
        uploadFile(fileName);
        active = false;
    }
}```
````

Comment: tried using cookies? session storage or local storage?

Comment: No , i don't tried

Comment: Are you sure `active` is never equal to `false`, or are you assuming so because the event handler still fires? Your `removeEventListener` is not doing what you think it is; you're using anonymous functions. You need to name your function in order to reference it and remove it as an event handler. You can do so by assigning it to a variable: `const handler = () => fileInput.click()`

Comment: It's good ?
```let active = true;
const handler = () => fileInput.click();
if (active) {
    clickedItem.addEventListener("click", () => {
        handler();
    });
} else {
    clickedItem.removeEventListener("click", () => {
        handler();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use local storage (you can use cookies and session storage too).

```
localStorage.setItem('active', 'true');

let active = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('active'));
if (active) {
    clickedItem.addEventListener("click", () => {
        fileInput.click();
    });
} else {
    clickedItem.removeEventListener("click", () => {
        fileInput.click();
    });
}
```

and inside fileInput set this:

```
localStorage.setItem('active', 'false');
```

Comment: Inside file input ? 
my file input : ```<input class="file-input" type="file" name="filee" multiple hidden>```

Comment: @MizaRRémi `fileInput.onchange`
inside this in js. replace with `active = false;`